# Returned Struct going invalid with Swift Result

Tags: ios, swift, asynchronous

I have an asynchronous function which when successful is supposed to pass back a Struct as part of a Result enum:

```
... 

DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 5) {
    guard let offset = self.accelerometerOffset else {
        self.calibrateCompleteCallback?(.failure(DeviceConnectError.faulted))
        return
    }

    self.calibrateCompleteCallback?(.success(offset))
}
```

I have stepped through this with the debugger, and at the point where I call
`self.calibrateCompleteCallback` the `offset` holds a valid struct, but on the receiving side the struct doesn't make it back. The result is "invalid", 0x0.

If I modify my struct to be a class, it gets passed back correctly and I can access the return. BUT WHY? Shouldn't the struct, as a value type, get copied and handed over to my caller?

Why is the reference staying valid. Here is the caller:

```
connectedDevice?.calibrate { result in
    switch(result) {
    case .success(let offset):
        self.accelerometerRecords.append(offset)
        self.continueButton.isEnabled = true
    default:
        return
    }
}
```

I created this sample code in a Swift playground which runs just fine.

```
import Foundation

struct Test {
    let x : Int = 0
    let y : Int = 0
    let name: String = "Dingo"
}

var closure : ((Result<Test, Error>) -> Void)?
func asyncJawn(completion: @escaping (Result<Test, Error>) -> Void) {
    closure = completion
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {
        closure?(.success(Test()))
    }
}

asyncJawn { result in
    switch(result) {
    case .success(let offset):
        print(offset.name)
    default:
        print("How did we get here?")
    }
}
```

Is is further complicated, and I think this is the root of my problem. The accelerometerOffset is being set from inside another closure that is called from a C function:

```
mbl_mw_datasignal_subscribe(acc_signal, bridge(obj: self)) { (context, data) in
    let obj: MblMwCartesianFloat = data!.pointee.valueAs();
    let _self : MetaWearDevice = bridge(ptr: context!) //bridge creates an UnsafeRawPointer
    _self.accelerometerOffset = ImuRecord(x: obj.x, y: obj.y, z: obj.z, time: Date())
}
```

Something is being deallocated, I guess, but what/where? My understanding was that using a value type should have provided some safety.

I have even tried

```
self.calibrateCompleteCallback?(.success(ImuRecord(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, z: 0.0, time: Date())))
```

To just pass back a brand new struct, but it too is invalid.